Problem with first column not visible
See this picture below. The leftmost and almost the whole of second column are not visible. Any Idea for how to solve this?
I'm trying to install Arch on a HPE Proliant Microserver Gen 8. In BIOS, everything looks fine. What you see on the image is Arch installation.
The computer only has vga output, which is what I'm using to the screens vga input. The monitor is a LG Flatron W1942T-PF. Tried to solve it with using 4:3 instead of widescreen, which is why you see a very wide black border.
I might mention that things did not work very well with a vga->hdmi adapter. Then I could not get neither the Bios screen, boot menu nor Linux installer. I bought an older screen to get that part working. With the newer screens, I only got the splash screen on startup, and then later Windows (which was installed when I got the computer) showed up. But as mentioned above, what you see on the image is a raw vga-vga connection.
Though not a preferable solution, maybe it's possible to do something with bash to right shift everything?
I have tried adjusting the screen settings, but when I moved everything right, then the right side started to disappear instead.


I think tmux supports vertical splitting, so in principle you could use it to make an as-narrow-as-possible split view on the left to cover that, but... that's a bit hacky and would only work as long as tmux is running, etc. Did you check what controls the display itself has in its menu? Usually there's at least something that can be used to adjust image coming from VGA, at least an auto-adjust. Which might make make it better, or not. Probably best to try when the screen is more or less full with anything but black.

What kind of connector (VGA, DP, HDMI, ...) are you using? Does the screen have a "automatic reset" button?

another thing you could try would be to see if the system is using the framebuffer driver, and see what happens if you disable that (in preference of the hardware text  mode)

Please [edit] your question and explain your setup. You mention a vga->hdmi adapter, is that relevant? How? Is that how you are connecting a screen? To what? Laptop? Desktop? Have you tried adjusting the screen's settings using the builtin screen buttons? This sort of thing is often more about the screen hardware itself.

@terdon Question updated. I just tried adjusting the screen. It kind of worked, but then I lost a bit of the right columns instead.

I don't see why this is relevant here. It's clearly a hardware mismatch between the excellent but ageing server and the monitor you've chosen to connect to it

@ChrisDavies Well it's not clear to me. :)

Is a Proliant Server EFI Capable?  I've only ever had to setup Dell PowerEdge... ie will you be using, or are you using UEFI to boot?  It looks like the GOP output is either not set to the standard 80c x 25r (which would give you at least 640x480) or the GOP is set correctly and the monitor passed the wrong EDID information to the kernel.

One more question: Does this behavior occur on other distributions (Debian, Fedora etc.)
